# Trennbare Verben in Fragen

Tags: question

> Arrange the following words into a sentence
>
> Theater-mitkommen-du-ins-?
>
> me: Kommst du ins Theater mit?
>
> Book: Kommst du mit ins Theater?

Why is the *mit* after the pronoun here?

Comment: Related question: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/55787/verb-position-with-modal-verbs

Comment: Not a case of extraposition; see [1](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/26741), [2](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/61273), [3](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/72618)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both solutions, yours and the book's solution are correct German. It's as so often a matter of emphasis of the question.

> Kommst Du ins Theater mit?

The emphasis is on coming *along*. This is less common and the same possibly could be done also by stressing *mit* in the other version.

> Kommst Du mit ins Theater?

The emphasis is on *to the theater*.

Comment: For clarification: the answer to the first question could be "No, I will get there on my own instead.", the answer to the second might be: "No, I have decided to watch a movie."

Answer (score 0):

The prefix/preposition *mit* is a bit special as it may switch roles rather freely. It's completely up to you if you want to emphasize on the verb (prefix) or the adverbial (preposition).

So both answers are okay. It's not specifically about questions either.

> Sie **kommt** am Abend ins Theater **mit.**

> Sie kommt am Abend **mit ins Theater.**